# Opening a Terminal window with the current directory set to a specific directory

Tags: bash, terminal, haiku

I want to set up a keyboard shortcut in Shortcuts that opens a Terminal window already `cd`'d to the desktop.  I've tried

```
Terminal ~/Desktop
Terminal cd ~/Desktop
```

But these don't work.  `Terminal --help` doesn't seem to yield an appropriate command-line option.  What do I need to do here?

Also, while a general solution to this would definitely be preferred, I would settle for being able to set the default directory for all Terminals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still not quite ideal with regards to the original question, but better than a solution affecting all Terminals: from [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.haiku.devel/23165) I discovered that from the desktop (i.e. if I first switch to an empty workspace, or otherwise give the desktop the focus somehow) I can Win+Alt+T to open a Terminal with cwd at the Desktop.

This tidbit of knowledge has the additional advantage that, if I were doing this to then `cd` more easily into a folder on the desktop (to run a newly downloaded app, for example), I can instead just open the folder and then hit Win+Alt+T.